# Driver.get("url") throw a timeout error if i dont click on the google chrome icon

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written some code in python using selenium.
Now I am doing driver.get("some URL")

It is now throwing a timeout exception.

But if I click on the browser before the timeout, it is running fine.

I want to know.. why is this happening.. Driver.get() is not able to process the URL until I click on the chrome browser?

I want to do driver.get() in the background but it is expecting me to click on the browser.
Please assist me

Comment: Are you using chromedriver 74?

Comment: no. I am using chrome version 75

Comment: Instead of clicking yourself, implement a click in selenium so that your script runs smoothly until you find a better solution to this problem.